# 'console' is 'undefined in the shell by using webpack with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json

I have a file `my-script.js` that only returns this:

```
console.log('Hi I'm working')
```

When I type in shell only

```
node my-script.js
```

This works successfully.
But I'd like it to work too when I typed in just this:

```
npm start
```

How to make it work?
Because it is generating an error message:

> Line: 1 Error: console is undefined Code: 800A1391 Source: Microsoft
>   JScript runtime error

I have a package.json file that points to this file to be the `start` but this is not resolving.

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "my-script.js",
  "scripts": {   
    "start": "my-script.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.41.2"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: Using node isn't implicit; use `"start": "node my-script.js"`, otherwise Windows is trying to run the script with its JScript engine (like if you double clicked the file).

Comment: thank you write again please like an answer, instead topic comment so I can upvote and close this topic

Comment: Btw, `console.log('Hi I'm working')` is a syntax error; you need to either use double quotes or escape the quote: `I\'m`

Comment: Thank you. I was knowing about it. I commited this mistake only here in stack overflow to describle the issue. In my app I was using another phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `node` in `start` script

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "my-script.js",
  "scripts": {   
    "start": "node my-script.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.41.2"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```